# F#: How to run fillMissing on only some specific columns of a Deedle data frame

Tags: f#, deedle

After an outer join of two data frames, I have the resulting data frame `f` that now contains columns A, B, C and D that all have missing values in them. I would like to fill in the missing values using `fillMissing`, but only for columns C and D.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out two ways to achieve that but neither is particularly pretty. I was wondering if there was a better functional way to do this.

### Method 1 (mutating):

```
fr
|> fun f -> 
    f?C <- f?C |> Series.fillMissing Direction.Forward
    f?D <- f?D |> Series.fillMissing Direction.Forward
    f
|> ...further processing...`
```

### Method 2 (functional but ugly):

```
fr 
|> Frame.mapCols 
    (fun k v -> match k with 
                | "C" | "D" -> v |> Series.fillMissing Direction.Forward 
                | _         -> v.As<obj>() )
|> ...further processing...
```

I would appreciate some input as to whether there is a better way.

EDIT: I just ran some timings over the real data frame I'm working with (~70K rows) for the three approaches (Method 3 is Foggy Finder's merge-based one) and got the following:

```
Method 1: Real: 00:00:00.003, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0    
Method 2: Real: 00:00:00.236, CPU: 00:00:00.234, GC gen0: 9, gen1: 3, gen2: 1    
Method 3: Real: 00:00:00.151, CPU: 00:00:00.156, GC gen0: 20, gen1: 1, gen2: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this option is better, but it is possible still so:

```
f
|> Frame.expandCols [| "A"; "B" |]
|> Frame.fillMissing Direction.Forward
|> Frame.merge (Frame.expandCols [| "C"; "D" |] f)
|> ...further processing...
```

Comment: @mt99, although, I have not been able to verify the correctness of this variant. So it is better if you will test it or show me MCVE.

Comment: No, it does indeed work, although I didn't bother with the `expandCols` as in my case all columns are floats. My initial concern with `merge` and `join` was that of efficiency, however, it is better vs Method 2 (see the EDIT of the question above).

Comment: interesting results I also thought that M2 should be faster.

Comment: Indeed, I edited the answer. On reflection, the timings of the methods in the answer probably belong there, so I'll leave it as is.

Comment: I agree (decided to clarify)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it in one of my functions dealing with the similar situation. You may sort the columns as you need after this.

```
let frame1 =
    rawFrame
    |> Frame.sliceCols ["C";"D"]
    |> Frame.fillMissing Direction.Forward
    |> Frame.dropSparseRows
// Left join with the other two columns
let frame2 = rawFrame |> Frame.sliceCols ["A";"B"]
frame1.Join(frame2, kind = JoinKind.Left)
```